# If -Then Proof Regarding Indexed Collection of Sets as an Input to a One-to One Function

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a function and let {${U_\alpha:\alpha\in\Lambda}$} be an indexed collection of subsets of $X$.
Prove that if $f$ is one-to-one, then $f(\bigcap\{U_\alpha:\alpha\in\Lambda\}) = \bigcap\{f(U_\alpha): \alpha \in \Lambda\}$.

Any guidance would be appreciated. I was thinking of doing a proof with the contrapositive. If $f(\bigcap\{U_\alpha:\alpha\in\Lambda\}) \neq \bigcap\{f(U_\alpha): \alpha \in \Lambda\}$, then $f$ is not one-to-one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the contrapositive if you want. Proving it directly is also not too bad.

Assume $f$ is one-to-one. Recall that this means that if $x,y\in X$ and $f(x)=f(y)$, then $x=y$. Equivalently, if $x\neq y$ then $f(x)\neq f(y)$.

To prove that $f\left(\bigcap_{\alpha\in\Lambda}U_{\alpha}\right)=\bigcap_{\alpha\in\Lambda}f(U_{\alpha})$ recall that you need to show that each set is included in the other.

Let $y\in f\left(\bigcap_{\alpha\in\Lambda}U_{\alpha}\right)$. Then $y=f(x)$ for some $x\in X$. More specifically, because $f(x)\in f\left(\bigcap_{\alpha\in\Lambda}U_{\alpha}\right)$ we have that $x\in U_{\alpha}$ for all $\alpha\in\Lambda$. If $x\in U_{\alpha}$ for all $\alpha$, then $f(x)=y\in f(U_{\alpha})$ for all $\alpha\in\Lambda$. This implies that

$$y=f(x)\in \bigcap_{\alpha\in\Lambda}f(U_{\alpha})$$

This gives you that $f\left(\bigcap_{\alpha\in\Lambda}U_{\alpha}\right)\subseteq\bigcap_{\alpha\in\Lambda}f(U_{\alpha})$. Now we need to show the other direction.

Let $y\in \bigcap_{\alpha\in\Lambda}f(U_{\alpha})$. Then $y\in U_{\alpha}$ for all $\alpha\in\Lambda$. This implies that for every $\alpha\in\Lambda$ there is an $x_{\alpha}\in U_{\alpha}$ such that $f(x_{\alpha})=y$. However, because $f$ is one-to-one we have that $f(x_{\alpha})=f(x_{\beta})$ for all $\alpha,\beta\in\Lambda$ implies that $x_{\alpha}=x_{\beta}$. Therefore there is a unique element $x\in X$ such that $f(x)=y$. This element $x$ must then be an element of $U_{\alpha}$ for all $\alpha\in\Lambda$. This is to say that $x\in\bigcap_{\alpha\in\Lambda}U_{\alpha}$. An immediate consequence of this is the following:

$$y=f(x)\in f\left(\bigcap_{\alpha\in\Lambda}U_{\alpha}\right)$$

which gives us that $f\left(\bigcap_{\alpha\in\Lambda}U_{\alpha}\right)\supseteq\bigcap_{\alpha\in\Lambda}f(U_{\alpha})$, establishing equality between the two sets.